# Live pagination on search bar with hooks in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys i am trying to implement the live pagination of searched items. I have done only the pagination for all the products but not for the searching ones and i am having some problems into writting it.
Thank you for your time.
This is app.js:

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);    
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);    
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [dataPerPage, setDataPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [filteredProduct, setFilteredProducts] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append(
      "Authorization",
      "Bearer xxx"
    );

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow",
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/WarehousStock", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setData(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  // this will run evertime one of the following state will change => data, currentPage, dataPerPage
  useEffect(() => {
    // generate dynamically columns from first object from array
    setColumns(
      Object.keys(data[0] || []).map((key) => ({
        Header: key,
        accessor: key,
      }))
    );

    filterData();
    
  }, [data, currentPage, dataPerPage]);

  var paginate = (pageNumber) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  function filterData() {
    const indexOfLastData = currentPage * dataPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstData = indexOfLastData - dataPerPage;

    // if there is a search term
    if (searchTerm !== '') {
      let result =
        data.filter(data => {
          return data.articleName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        })
      result = result.slice(indexOfFirstData, indexOfLastData)
      setCurrentData([...result])
    } else {
      // if there is no a search term
      setCurrentData(data.slice(indexOfFirstData, indexOfLastData));
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    filterData();


  }, [searchTerm])


  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  return (
    <Styles>
      <div className="SearchButton"><input type="text" placeholder="Search name of product" onChange={event => { setSearchTerm(event.target.value) }} /></div>
      <Table columns={columns} data={currentData} />
      <Pagination
        dataPerPage={dataPerPage}
        totalData={data.length}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
    </Styles>
  );
}
```

This is the pagination component:

```
const Pagination = ({ dataPerPage, totalData, paginate }) => {
  const pageNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalData / dataPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="pagination mt-4">
        {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
          <li key={number} className="page-item">
            <a onClick={() => paginate(number)} href="!#" className="page-link">
              {number}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Does it error? What does it do/not do that you are/aren't expecting?

Comment: I don't know how to handle the live pagination of searched products, i am stucked. i don't have errors, thank you @DBS